# Can Chromedriver be used to report secure/insecure page status on HTTPS URLs?

Tags: java, selenium, https, selenium-chromedriver

My company is in the process of changing all our URLs from HTTP to HTTPS. One of the most useful tools to us is manually using the console in Chrome to view the information on the Security and Network tabs to find the items that are preventing the page from being secure (showing the green padlock).

I am using Java code that reads through a local text file of HTTPS URLs to test.

Using Chromedriver, can it tell me if a URL is secure or insecure (as it would show me if I used Chrome manually)? Also, can it tell me what is causing a page to not be secure?

I'm hoping someone has tackled this one already, but can't find anything on it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: No replies at all? :(